# How to add time delay before copy message since it editing after few seconds. Discord.js, node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

The script is copying my messages from my main server to the secondary. But I need to add some delay because sometimes I edit embeds. (it send always the first one before editing). What I can use to delay getting text messages and embed messages before sending them?

```
import Selfcore from "selfcore";

const client = new Selfcore()
const gateway = new Selfcore.Gateway(
    "token"
);
gateway.on("message",  m => { 
    if(m.channel_id === "939824755664629813") {
        let content = m.content ? m.content : { embeds: [m.embeds[0]] };
        client.sendWebhook(
            "https://discord.com/api/webhooks/1062393339422457866/token", 
            content
        );
    }
});
```

Comment: The same way you would delay anything in JavaScript, using `setTimeout()`

Comment: FYI: If you're adding arbitrary delays, then you're doing it wrong. You might want to look into using a promise-based API instead.

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking is not possible with the package you are using. You are not using a fully featured bot package like [discord.js](https://discord.js.org/#/). You are using `selfcore`, a simple package for running simple self-bots.

More specifically, the `message` event runs every time a message is posted. Selfcore doesn't have a way to call Discord to ask for a specific message and its edited content.